# How can I parse 3h to java?(cant set a variable starting with number)

Tags: java, json

I have to parse the response from an API to java Object and print them with json format. I managed to do it, however a varibale in response is "3h". I cant name a variable with name 3h in Java, so I cant parse the value in my Object. Is something I can do? I am using com.google.gson.Gson library. Thanks.

"rain":{"3h":3.4375},"

```
public class Rain{
    private float threeh;
    public float getThreeh() {
        return threeh;
    }

    public void setThreeh(float threeh) {
        this.threeh = threeh;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which `json`-library are you using?

Comment: I am using com.google.gson.Gson;

Comment: You may want to [edit] your question and add that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at the library called GSON, especially using the `@SerializedName` annotation. Your class will become something like that:

```
public class Rain {
    @SerializedName("3h")
    float threeh;
}
```

You can read more about that annotation here : https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html